# Best way to get data off a computer with no support for USB or Ethernet?

Tags: file-transfer, windows-98, data-transfer

A customer has a computer running Windows 98 (I know, cringe) and needs to take some data off the computer to put on a new laptop.

I've tried using USB, but Windows 98 doesn't have USB storage drivers. I thought I'd transfer the data via Ethernet instead, but the computer doesn't have an Ethernet port.

I then decided to try and burn the data to a CD, but we only had blank DVDs on hand. And of course, the drive doesn't write to DVDs.

The only way I can think of getting the data off the drive now is by taking it out of the computer and using a USB cable to connect it directly to the laptop, but I don't really want to poke around the insides of that PC.

Does anyone have any better ideas to get the data off the computer?

Comment: So, the PC has USB ports but you can't find Win98 drivers for a flash drive, right? is this 98 or 98SE?

Comment: When you do finally decide to take the drive out of the system and access it directly with another computer **wear a dust mask** - the inside of that machine is going to be full of stuff (i.e. small amounts of plant pollen, human and animal hairs, human and animal skin, textile fibers, paper fibres, minerals from outdoor soil, and many other materials ) that you don't want to be breathing.

Comment: Print everything. Surely there must be a parallel port.

Comment: @mtone Ironically, that's why she got a new laptop. After buying a new printer she found it didn't work with 98, so she decided to get a new laptop too as the PC was getting old anyway.

Comment: @Sparx Yes, it has USB ports but I tried a USB thumb drive and portable USB hard drive and neither worked. No idea if or where I can find drivers for USB storage devices.

Comment: Added answer with generic usb mass storage driver. see if it works. Also check manufacturer website for old win98 drivers.

Comment: @Sparx I hope it does! The manufacturer (Tiny) has since gone bust...

Comment: Go buy some blank CD's?

Comment: I do find it amusing that you can write a CD on it but don't have USB storage drivers available.  Either go get some CD's or pull the drive.

Comment: @Connor W - you need to check manufacturer of the thumb drive (or USB external drive) for Win98 drivers, not the PC manuf.; Win98 has USB stack but no drivers for external storage, so those should be coming with the drives

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk :)

Comment: 1. Write word macro to open and scroll each document from top to bottom. 2. Record the monitor with a video camera. 3. Use virtualdub to decompose video into single images. 4. Feed into an OCR reader. 5. Reassemble documents removing overlaps.

Comment: XD XD XD XD XD XD

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To be honest, taking the drive out would take about 30 seconds, it's probably the easiest way.

Comment: Yep. Also save you the hassle and potential risks of choosing what files to burn.

Comment: That probably is the easiest option, but I dont want to damage anything in the process. I would have no problem if it was my own, but its not and it's over 10 years old. Maybe I'm just being paranoid.

Comment: to be honest... you're being paranoid.  If it breaks while your fixing it it's either because you don't know what you're doing (doubt it), or (in reality) it was already about to break.

Comment: @Connor W, removing the hard disk is just taking out two cables: the data (IDE) and power cables.

Comment: You can get laptop drive enclosures cheap... they turn an old laptop drive into an external (portable) drive. Then its just a simple USB connection to your new computer. Something like: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817145752

Comment: Also touch a heater or the (plugged in, but turned off at the switch in the back) computer while doing it. Just touching the metal case which is physically connected to the PSU will suffice. You're grounded like this. This will keep you free of statics. You can't zap your circuits this way :)

Comment: Nice answer, quite outside the box.

Comment: I'd go with being paranoid & finding either a blank CD, or a bootable linux CD (so you can use USB devices). Older systems like this can be quick fragile, and I'd want the best backup I could get before I started taking parts out.

Comment: just make sure it's turned off first...

Comment: If you can buy a hard drive enclosure, you can also buy blank CDs.

Comment: I'll join the paranoid brigade - on a machine of that age I would try all options that don't require it to be opened and bits removed before I'd consider diving in. A couple of years back I opened an HP server (2006-7 era) on a workshop bench (fully static safe area) to remove the CPU heatsink and check the exact model and stepping of Xeon processor so we could get a matching second one, and when I put the heatsink back and powered up the motherboard had failed. It was probably coincidence coupled with the fact that the machine had been running 24/7 for months but it was still a write-off.

Comment: Uhm, removing the CPU heatsink is not really comparable with unplugging a hard disk drive... If you are not too stupid, then you don't even need to touch the mainboard..

Comment: True, but you are in the vicinity and may disturb cables and connectors  + the machine has to be moved and maybe powered down after a long period of running. Many a technician will tell you of machines that switch off never to come on again.

Answer (score 41):

Go buy some CDs at the local supermarket or computer store!

Comment: Yeah I may do, but I'd rather not have to if there is an easier  and cheaper way. Especially as you cant buy single CDs, and that's all I want.

Comment: Well, if you want to drive to Lewes in East Sussex I'll gladly give you a couple!

Comment: Or ask around.  Someone in the neighborhood probably has a couple old blank CDs in a drawer or old shoe box.  Offer the first one to find one a pint in exchange!

Comment: A single CD isn't worth anywhere near the cost of a pint!

Comment: “[...] and cheaper way” – time is money, and as of now, you spent more time discussing how to solve a non-issue than some cheap CDs cost..

Comment: You can buy single CDs, at least here in the States!  Big box stores like Wal-mart usually have them on the shelf in individual plastic sleeves.

Answer (score 40):

download  [Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)  CD or USB, boot from there and it will support USB

using serial port will take forever (depend on the data volume)

there are also DB25 Male / DB25 Male 15C Parallel Data Transfer Cable (norton commander or Windows 'Direct Cable Connection.")

[boot Linux from floppy](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/index.php/Boot_Floppies) - but it is not GUI :)

DVD - [KNOPPIX](http://knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html) this GUI is very lightweith no problems even with 128MB

you also can do a backup of user's data if HDD dies (it is about a time)

Comment: A 98-era machine won't be USB-bootable.  And they don't have any blank CDs...

Comment: I wouldn't even bet on CD bootable either for that era and many modern live CDs don't support El Torito anymore (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29)

Comment: he said "...the drive doesn't write to DVDs." so maybe reads DVDs

Comment: @Colin Pickard, with a GRUB floppy, you can boot from USB. I've done it on a P3.

Comment: @jet Yup, I put in a DVD with data on it and it read the data fine. @Colin Pickard @Alan I have Ubuntu on a DVD, didn't think to try that actually but it may work. It's questionable as you said as to whether it will boot from a DVD or not.

Comment: I would expect a bootable CD to work, but I wouldn't expect just any modern linux desktop to run well on a Win98-era machine.  Go for something like Puppy Linux or DSL linux.

Comment: I wouldn't run Ubuntu (especially a LiveCD) on a computer which was made for Win98) because of a possibly low RAM. See my answer.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Sounds good, but God knows where I'm going to find a floppy disk! Letalone another computer which I can use to write Linux to it

Comment: @Connor W, that was my comment, please scroll down the page ;)

Comment: DVD - http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html this GUI is very lightweith no problems even with 128MB

Comment: Definitly the best solution.

Comment: I wouldn't get sidetracked with the Linux/ubuntu idea most windows 98 boxes came with 32 or 64 megs of ram and very seldom were upgraded to 128 - you likely wont have enough memory to load and run even a lean distro

Comment: @kloucks: why can't you? Some of the leanest but complete Linux distros could fit all of their files in a 64 MB thumbdrives. The latest Linux 2.6 kernel (without initramfs and only relevant drivers included) is about 2.5 MB, which can be made much smaller with some effort. You probably are not going to have all the Compiz jazz, but some minimalists wm, e.g. twm could fit and have lots of space left; Firefox is out of the question, but dillo or even links is fine. The extreme minimalist Linux distribution can fit a whole system in 2.5MB.

Comment: @Lie Ryan what you're suggesting is a Great Idea if the OP is a linux wiz like you but he's not and your suggestion is no use to him because he want to move the files sooner not 3 months from now when he's mastered linux in small memory spaces. You and I both know that the standard distros will not work in a 64mg RAM environment. By the way I was referring to working RAM not thumbdrives - doesn't matter what size your media is if your box is memory starved which most Win 98 boxes were (remember most video cards of that era shared ram so you usually didn't have even 64mg)

Comment: @kloucks: this is the first time anyone had called me a linux wiz; I don't think I had any special skill with compiling Linux that anyone cannot learn in one day. Even with standard configuration, Linux kernel is about 15 MB (mostly drivers for the weirdest systems that won't be loaded to RAM at runtime). Since the dawn of computing, the size of RAM is always smaller than the size of the primary storage, if you can fit the whole system into 64MB, you can run it on 64 MB RAM. 64 MB of RAM is plenty for many off-the-shelf minimalist Linux distros.

Comment: Surely, I'm not recommending Ubuntu or other full-featured distros that would dazzle your eyes with fancy animations and other stuffs. You do not need any special knowledge to work with 10 year old systems, just download an off-the-download-shelf minimalist Linux, and they should work Ok for 10 year old systems. You might have need more extreme measures to work with 20-30 year old systems, but 10 year old is still young and fit for Linux.

Comment: +1 for 'Laplink' Back to back Serial/Parallel connection

Answer (score 15):

[Hyperterm file transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms818664.aspx) with a null modem cable? Odds are good the old box has one and cheap USB ones can be used on the new laptop. Even for a CDROM of data it should complete overnight.

Or you could even do full PPP over the serial port to another PC running a pppd.

Comment: Masochistic, but doable!

Comment: If CD-R, Ethernet and HDD removal are out there isn't much left besides RS-232 and the printer!

Comment: If you're going to go buy a null modem cable you might as well just buy some blank CDs, then you have data transfer and a backup in one.  CDs are probably cheaper and easier to find locally too.

Comment: Huh. I would have suggested tar + compression for some reason... Then again, I don't think I've tried that over raw serial, so maybe it would hit a transmission error and die.

Answer (score 15):

Find, buy or scrounge a PCI network card.

Comment: Not a bad idea actually. Cant believe I didnt think of that already

Comment: Apparently you ruled it out..."but I dont really want to poke around the insides of that PC."

Comment: In the case of a laptop of that era, you may well be able to put in a PCMCIA card, which wouldn't require any poking around.

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking for drivers for a USB flash drive for Win98 FE or SE, [see this page](http://www.technical-assistance.co.uk/kb/usbmsd98.php) for a generic USB Mass Storage Driver.

Right click on **My Computer** and select **Properties**

On the System Properties page that opens up click on the **General** tab, if it is not already on that page.
Under the **System** heading, look for the version number (see right)

```
* Version 4.10.1998 is the original version of Windows 98 (98FE)
* Version 4.10.2222 is Windows 98 Second Edition (98SE)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Had no idea there were two editions of 98. Only problems is, how do you install the drivers to a computer with no internet connection or USB storage functionality?

I'm really wondering how people lived with 98!

Comment: You didn't mention that there was no internet access. I don't suppose you could connect an external dial-up modem. is there any ISP in your locale that still offers dial-up internet access?

Comment: @Connor: You may want to edit that into your answer.

Comment: And this is exactly the situation in which a floppy drive in a new computer still makes sense! If your new computer had one, you could easily transfer the driver! So, go buy a floppy drive ;)

Answer (score 4):

Back in the day, we used special parallel or serial port cables and file transfer software to move data from PC to PC. The most famous package I remember was LapLink and it came with special cable and software for just this problem. Wikipedia describes the LapLink cable as for parallel port - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable, but I know I have in a junkbox somewhere a couple of universal serial port null-modem cables. Perhaps, I'm mixing up the Direct Cable Connection feature of Windows that apparently is available up through Windows XP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_cable_connection. If you're interested in pursuing, Microsoft still has some instructions online - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298446.

Comment: I used LapLink at one point and it worked well. Same with Direct Cable Connection. There's probably something about the latter in Windows' built-in Help.

Comment: You recall correctly - LapLink supports both parallel and serial port transfers. Note that it's painfully slow compared to modern transfer speeds; I'd use it to transfer the USB Mass Storage drivers mentioned in another answer, and continue thence.

Answer (score 4):

The two most economical ways to do it would be to, as many suggest would be to:

1. remove the harddrive and put it into another machine that you can copy the files off
2. buy the smallest, cheapest stack of CDs and burn copies of those.
3. Variant on 2, buy a cheap stack of CD's, burn a very lightweight Linux distro (Knoppix works fine) on it, and transfer off via a USB stick (assuming you can actually boot to a CD, that is)

The alternatives involve buying curiously expensive cables (it's harder and harder to find a Parallel cable, let alone whether the laptop computer you want to transfer the files *to* actually has said connector) coupled with very slow transfers (would take more time than to walk down to any computer superstore/Office Supply store and get some CDs).  You didn't mention whether the Windows98 computer has "open" PCI slots for an ethernet card, so that route might be difficult (finding an ISA ethernet card isn't easy anymore).  Plus you would NOT want to connect that computer to the Internet in any way shape or form.

An external USB enclosure that supports IDE (most likely what the Windows 98 computer's harddrive is) are fairly inexpensive (in the US, approximately 20-50 dollars).  Though plugging it into any computer that *can* actually transfer via USB would be ideal.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just get a USB<->IDE converter (see the review on [cool tools](http://www.kk.org/cooltools/archives/004867.php)).  You wouldn't even need to remove the drive from the case if the connectors fit in behind the drive. Just plug in the data cable between the laptop and the drive, plug in the power, ????, profit!

Answer (score 3):

Since the computer runs Win98, it has probably not enough RAM to run a full-featured distro like [Ubuntu/Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com) from a LiveCD. Therefore, I recommend using a lighter Linux distribution like [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) which uses 175 in "Live" mode. It supports USB, so you can plug in an external USB harddisk and copy the files. You should have patience though, Win98 computers do not (often) have USB2.0 ports.

The best alternative I can think of is removing the hard disk from the computer, and put it in a newer computer with better hardware. You might need an [IDE to SATA cable](http://www.nextag.com/ide-to-sata-cable/shop-html) as well. If you do not like opening your new computer, or wish to transfer data to the laptop directly, buy an [IDE to USB cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I0VIYE).

Comment: Linux can run on pretty minimum resources.

Comment: KronoS, I'm not talking about Linux, but *Ubuntu/Linux*. Altough it can run on 256ish RAM, there are faster alternatives.

Comment: What the f*** is *Ubuntu/Linux*? ( ["official censoring rules"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142) )

Comment: Ubuntu is a Operating System, ran on the Linux kernel. Added a link for your convenience: http://www.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and fastest solution would be to go to your local electronic store and buy a case of CDs, R or RW, whichever you prefer.

However, another way to transfer the files would be via the network, but you didn't specify if there was a NIC in the PC.

Yet another way would be to connect an old Zip drive and get the files off of the machine that way.

And finally, the last way I can think of would be to take the HD out and plug it into another computer that can write DVDs and then simply burn the DVDs, assuming you have a computer on hand with those capabilities.

Comment: I wouldn't certainly  wouldn't call burning CDs one the fastest ways to do it. The OP also mentioned there was no Ethernet port, so that's out, too. Zip or Jaz drives might work, if he can find or borrow one. Removing the HD is probably the fastest and most painless suggestion, IMHO.

Comment: Another possibly nice thing about IOmega Zip or Jaz drives is that they can both be connected to through a printer port.

Answer (score 2):

This calls for kermit! if it worked on XTs then it should work now. Do you have a serial cable?

But seriously, you could have got a next-day delivery of CDRs by now. Before you move the drive to another PC make sure it has support for the drive. The old drive is probably IDE and most new PCs are sata only.

Answer (score 2):

Buy (or make) a laplink cable
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable

Higher bandwidth than a null modem cable.

You can find the software you'll need easily enough with a google search, and you can transfer it to the Win98 box with a floppy disk.

I have one I keep around just because I've ran into similar scenarios in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If you **absolutely** cannot take out the hard drive, and cannot use a USB flash drive, then you *can* use the parallel port on the system to transfer files.  However, speeds are going to be SLOW (I'm talking dial-up era speeds) so to be fully honest with you, take out the hard drive and transfer the files from there.

It will probably be even faster than anything else since 98 (to my knowledge) doesn't have USB 2.0 support and the processing power/memory usage for transferring files will slow it down as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Internet access on the old machine, you could use something like [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com) which will let you upload and download, or "share", files & folders among multiple computers running different OSs. I'm not sure if their client software directly supports Win98, but even if it doesn't you can use its web-based interface to do almost all the same things (uploading and download shared files) -- I've done that with someone I know who has a Mac with an old unsupported version of OS X.

A free account comes with 2 GB of storage space -- and if that isn't enough you can transfer the files in batches.

Comment: User doesn't have internet access. That's one of the main hitches.

Answer (score 0):

Buy this, or equivalent.  Afterward, keep for future similar data retrieval.  As an IT tech, a device like this is well worth the investment.  The one I have, I have used 3 or 4 times in critical situations.  Never fails to provide the best solution for the type of problem you have.

http://www.frys.com/product/5357858