# Generic Windows 98 USB Drive drivers?

Tags: drivers, usb-storage, windows-98

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get data off a computer with no support for USB or ethernet?](https://superuser.com/questions/237198/best-way-to-get-data-off-a-computer-with-no-support-for-usb-or-ethernet)

I've got an old Win98 machine that  I'd like to pull some data off of.  (Tens of gigs of data, actually.)  The machine still runs fine, but due to the age, it doesn't have a cd burner, and the pre-NT networking won't connect to SMB shares without a fair amount of wrenching on the registry that I don't really want to do.

What I really want to do is plug in an external USB hard drive and copy the files.  But - Win98 didn't ship with generic USB drive drivers, and external drives don't ship with them these days.

Can anyone point me at a reputable generic driver I can install?

Comment: An [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/237198/best-way-to-get-data-off-a-computer-with-no-support-for-usb-or-ethernet/237213#237213) to a [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/237198/best-way-to-get-data-off-a-computer-with-no-support-for-usb-or-ethernet) linked to [these drivers](http://www.technical-assistance.co.uk/kb/usbmsd98.php).

Answer (score 1):

There's generic USB drivers, but they're a pain to find. If i recall correctly, [this should work](http://www.technical-assistance.co.uk/kb/usbmsd98.php)