# How to recover files from Windows 95

Tags: migration, windows-95

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to get data off a computer with no support for USB or ethernet?](https://superuser.com/questions/237198/best-way-to-get-data-off-a-computer-with-no-support-for-usb-or-ethernet)

I have a friend, he has a computer that has windows 95 operating system. he is using Lotus with it. and he has very important document in this computer.

Computer doesnt have a floppy or a CD Writer. I doubt windows 95 would support writing CDs anyway. No USB ports. No internet.

He wants to take those important files from Windows 95.

I suggested that he can connect the hard drive to another machine and rescue the files like that.

Is there an alternative. What can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Lets see, No CD, floppy, network card, usb...connect the hard drive to another PC, that is about all you can do easily.

Comment: The OS makes no difference, since it is a lack of hardware issue, the other post has all the solutions that also apply to you.